# Why slice append element not update referenced element?

Tags: go, append, slice

This rule is what I know about slice in Go

- When the number of elements and the width of the capacity are the same (len(fruits) == cap(fruits)), the new element resulting from append() is the new reference.
- When the number of elements is less than the capacity (len(fruits) < cap(fruits)), the new element is placed into the capacity range, causing all other slice elements with the same reference to change in value.

I have code like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //declare slice
    var fruits = []string{"banana", "mango", "tomato"}

    //using two index technique to make slice
    var newFruits = fruits[1:2]

    //append element to fruits slice
    fruits = append(fruits, "papaya")
    
    //append element to newFruits slice
    newFruits = append(newFruits, "dragon")

    fmt.Println(cap(fruits)) //2
    fmt.Println(cap(newFruits)) //6
    fmt.Println(newFruits) //[mango dragon]
    fmt.Println(fruits) //[banana mango tomato papaya]
    
}
```

why the value of fruits is not [banana mango dragon papaya]?

Comment: Both of your "rules" do not describe how slices work. Start by understanding slices by forgetting "reference". There are no reverences in Go. Then read https://go.dev/blog/slices and https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the code works:

Just before appending `papaya` to `fruits`,

```
fruits = {"banana", "mango", "tomato"}
```

and `newFruits` points to the same array as `fruits` but starting from `mango`.

When you append `papaya` to `fruits`, a new array is created with capacity=6, because the capacity of `fruits` is 3. `fruits` now points to this new array, with 4 values:

```
fruits = {"banana", "mango", "tomato", "papaya"}
```

`newFruits` still points to the old `fruits` array, and contains 2 elements.

Comment: I see... "a new array is created" and "newFruits still points to the old fruits" makes me understand